# how to simplify my sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query, but it takes about 15 seconds to finish.. how can i simplyfy it to get same result in less time? my problem is that i need all of this data at ones.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT c.client_id, c.client_name, c.client_bpm,
                   c.client_su_name, c.client_maxbpm, s.bpm, 
                   s.timestamp, m.mesure_id, ms.currentT
    FROM tbl_clients c, tbl_meting m, tbl_sensor_meting s, 
                        tbl_magsens_meting ms
    WHERE c.client_id = m.client_id
    AND (m.mesure_id = s.id_mesure
            OR m.mesure_id = ms.id_mesure)
    AND m.live =1
    ORDER BY s.timestamp DESC
        ) AS mesure
          GROUP BY mesure.client_id
```

Comment: What is the subquery supposed to do? Can you rewrite it using JOINs? The `OR` part seems dubious at least.

Comment: Does the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` tell you anything useful?

Comment: Do you have relevant indexes? Can you post EXPLAIN results?

Comment: the result is usefull for me and i came with this one. It gives me several lines where live = 1. and the rest WHERE and AND (..OR..) part is also important. With 3 tables it goes in less than 0.3 sec. but this way.. it is not as quick

Comment: Your (or) where condition is actually equivalent to the union of 2 cross joins. So, the subquery is getting many more results than you probably want. You don't see them because you have the `GROUP BY` in the external query. If you describe what you want the query to show, someone may arrive at a better query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem may be the `OR` condition from your `WHERE` clause?  You seem to be trying to join to one table or another, which you can't do.  So I've replaced it with a `LEFT JOIN`, so in the event no related records exist nothing will be returned.

I also took out your `GROUP BY`, as I don't think it was required.

```
SELECT c.client_id, c.client_name, c.client_bpm,
               c.client_su_name, c.client_maxbpm, s.bpm, 
               s.timestamp, m.mesure_id, ms.currentT
FROM         tbl_clients         c
  JOIN       tbl_meting          m   ON m.client_id = c.client_id
  LEFT JOIN  tbl_sensor_meting   s   ON s.id_mesure = m.mesure_id
  LEFT JOIN  tbl_magsens_meting  ms  ON ms.id_mesure = m.mesure_id
WHERE m.live = 1
ORDER BY s.timestamp DESC
```

Comment: whithout ORDER BY it gives me whole table :) and i need only one record.. i cant quite enplane what i was doing but it worked... one moment i will try this way

Comment: many thanks!! this one worked in less than 0.2sec.. its much better than my 15 sec :D